# Статьи представлены к публикациям - так можно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Я тогда увлеклась буковками до такой степени, что даже стала главным
>   редактором одновременно нескольких изданий и проводила время в общении
>   с начинающими журналистами.

Этот маленький абзац - в пояснение к "уже" в следующем.

> ...Пошла учиться в МГУ на исторический факультет – отделение истории
>   искусств, где моими преподавателями стали ведущие российские ученые.
>   Под их руководством я совершила несколько вполне уверенных шагов, и **к
>   публикациям были представлены теперь уже мои научные статьи**,
>   посвящённые русской архитектуре XVIII века.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь возможен только вариант с **единственным** числом, поскольку в данном контексте публикация - это абстракция, **действие** как таковое (не имеет значения, сколько раз оно совершается по отношению к множественным сущностям, когда и где - их просто планируется *опубликовать*). Точно так же статьи не принимают "к рассмотрениям" (нет такого мероприятия, в отличие от *слушаний/прений*)

Видимо, ошибка связана с существованием в иных контекстах понятия "публикация" в значении **материала**, *выхода статьи в конкретном журнале тогда-то* (на две таких статьи уже можно сослаться словами "эти публикации интересны").

Comment: Саша, Вы наш спаситель - и мой, и автора.

Answer (score 1):

Такой вариант встречается:

https://studfiles.net/preview/1721974/page:8/

Требования к тезисам доклада и научным статьям, представляемым к публикации.

Comment: Jasmin, извини, пожалуйста: меня убедил в справедливости сомнений ответ Alex_ander.

Comment: Так у меня вроде бы ед. число в ответе, если об этом речь.

Comment: Так в вопросе *к публикациям*. У Вас свой пример (который я, возможно, неверно поняла), а мне требовалось объяснение ошибки в моём тексте!

Answer (score 1):

**публика́ция** (лат. publicatio)
1) доведение до всеобщего сведения посредством печати, радиовещания или телевидения;
2) печатание в различных изданиях (газетах, журналах, книгах) какой-либо работы, работ;
3) текст, опубликованный в каком-л, издании.
**[Новый словарь иностранных слов. 2009](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_fwords/29874)**

Если статей несколько и издательств несколько, тогда вполне приемлемы "публикации":
*В данном разделе представлены официальные статистические публикации... по Архангельской области.*
*За одновременными публикациями в российских СМИ со ссылкой на "источник в Кремле" стоит Кириенко...*

**Дополнение** (к комментарию)

*Старшим партнером юридической группы... **подготовлены публикации** об особенностях применения статьи 366 ГК РБ, а также о нюансах учреждения хозяйственного общества одним участником.*
***...в представленных к опубликованию*** материалах содержатся сведения, относящие их к продукции военного назначения... (публикация = опубликование)

Comment: Римма Михайлова, мне бы быть уверенной не в том, что нечто можно представить к публикации, а именно в конструкции *к публикациям были представлены мои научные статьи*. Остаюсь в неуверенности...

Comment: Я дополнила свой ответ

Comment: Спасибо,  Римма ! И простите, я как-то машинально читала Вашу фамилию как отчество, а сама, помню, сетовала, что Вы ко мне по фамилии обращаетесь. Извините.

Comment: Да, было такое дело! Оказалось, что просто не нужно ставить пробел между словами.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько значений слова "публикация". В данном случае, я считаю, говорится о статьях "представленных к **опубликованию**". У меня язык не поворачивается произнести это во множественном числе.

В другом значении ("публикация = статья") может использоваться множественное число, но это вряд ли имеет отношение к вопросу.

Comment: Мне же тоже чуется что-то не то... Головоломкой по автору!